# ERROR: Slony-I: Table is replicated and cannot be modified on a subscriber node

Tags: database, postgresql, slony

I recently restored a db (postgresql ver.9.3.5) from backup that was taken from a slony standby.  The restored db is in separate environment from the backup source.
But am getting below error when i attempted to insert a row.

ERROR:  Slony-I: Table is replicated and cannot be modified on a subscriber node

Is there any slony update to run before i can use the db?